# Blazor site without the default nav bar

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I want to create a blazor site that does not present the default side bar (or any bar for that matter) only my single page, like a regular website would. I was not able to find any information about how to do this. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: You just remove the relevant razor/html-code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the \Shared folder you will find MainLayout.razor .

Just edit it to your taste, a minimal version would be:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="main">
   @Body
</div>
```